# Intellij set runtime variables for run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I have maven run configuration, where I call:

```
liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1 -Dliquibase.clearCheckSums=true
```

Is there any way to display some popup to provide for instance rollbackCount before running the configuration itself instead of editing the configuration?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not what kind of solution are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ itself can't prompt you for commandline parameters. But you can achieve this with a workaround:

1) Create a `.bat` file that prompts you for an input and creates a simple properties file (assuming you're using windows)

```
@echo off
set /p id="ID: "
echo liquibase.rollbackCount=%id% > config.properties
```

2) Load the properties file from maven. This uses the properties plugin for maven. If you're already using the plugin the dependency must not be inserted.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency> 
...
  <build>    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${basedir}/config.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

3) Execute the bat before running maven

1. Edit your run configuration
2. Add "External Tool" to "Before Launch"
3. Set Working directory to: `$ProjectFileDir$` and Program to your `.bat` file

When running the program in IntelliJ a commandline should now open with the batch file asking for the ID. Then the properties file will be written, maven executes and loads that file.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

- configure your Maven job in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog
- set the checkbox `Show this page` as shown in my screenshot
- when you call the run configuration, a dialog appears and it should be possible to edit the field `command line` or something else

[image: Run/Debug Configuration for a maven task]

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think there is, but you can duplicate a configuration quite easily using the 'Copy Configuration' button and then have a few similar ones with just the changes you want.